# Simple Accordion Menu in ios

Tags: objective-c, accordion

I want to develop a simple accordion menu in ios but I could not find an example of the way I want.
Accordion menu headers to include an image(arrow) and text. Clicking on this text its content will be visible. If clicked again it must be closed.

For example:

```
>> Title1
>> Title2
>> Title3
```

If click Title1 it expands.

```
<< Title1
  Including text information...
>> Title2
>> Title3
```

How to make the easiest way? 
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Refer this link https://www.github.com/kuon/ios-example-accordion

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is a UITableView, with functions on the row selection delegate methods to manipulate the underlying data and add rows and re-render with the cell animation that slides the cells in from the top.

[Here's a tutorial from Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a popover view, though those are only available on iPad. Otherwise some variation of a modal view for iPhone might suit your needs.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for answer Karoly but I mean, this is not. I have to add more descriptive.

Comment: Ah, alright, I see now. I think in that case Dan Ray's suggestion is more of what you are looking for.